# Hungman game code in python show different output

Tags: python, while-loop

I try to design a hungman game.

Hangman is a word guessing game. The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, representing each letter of the word. If the guessing player (In this case your model) suggests a letter which occurs in the word, letter is revealed in all its correct positions. If the suggested letter does not occur in the word, then it is marked as a wrong attempt. The guesser can make at most 8 wrong attempts for predicting a given word.

The code block is

```
import random
import string

def get_valid_word(words):
    #randomly choice words from list
    word = random.choice(words)
    # the loop iterate until we get the word that does not have - or space on it.
    return word

def hungman():
    words = ["dog", "frog", "hog", "slob", "bacon", "avacado"]
    word = get_valid_word(words)
    #keep track what already been guessed in the word
    word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    #what the user had guessed
    used_letters = set()

    #getting user input
    while len(word_letters) > 0:
        #letters used
        print("You have used these letters: ")
        print(", ".join(used_letters))
        #what the current word is
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-'  for letter in word]
        print("Current word: ")
        print(", ".join(word_list))
        user_letter = str(input("Guess a letter : ")).upper()

        '''
        If this is the valid character in the alphabet that user has not use yet
        then user going to add this to his or her used letter list
        '''
        if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
            used_letters.add(user_letter)
            # if the letter that user just guessed in the word, it would be removed from word_letters
        if user_letter in word_letters:
            word_letters.remove(user_letter)
            print(" ")

        elif user_letter in used_letters:
            print("Sorry! this seems to be already used charater. Try again: ")

        else:
            print("Invalid input. Try again ")

hungman()
```

I did not get the correct output

The output that I got:

```
Guess a letter : S
S
-
Guess a letter : a
SYou have use this letters: ', ' A
-
Guess a letter : d
DYou have use this letters: ', ' SYou have use this letters: ', ' A
-
Guess a letter : u
DYou have use this letters: ', ' UYou have use this letters: ', ' SYou have use this letters: ', ' A
```

`print("Current word: ', ' ".join(word_list))` this line dis not print anything in my output.

Actual Output:

```
guess a letter: e
You have used this letters : E
Current word : -----E

guess a letter: a
You have used this letters : E A
Current word : ---A-E

guess a letter: i
You have used this letters : I E A
Current word : ---A-E
```

I unable to understand what is the wrong with my code.

Comment: You better check the indentation. The code is full of syntax error and I cannot run it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The code was a little hard to follow but I scaled it back a little and pulled some of your dependencies.

Here is a version of the code that works. I'm positive it doesn't take into account several things that could go wrong, like entry of double letters. Example: "ad", "ba" etc.

```
import random
import string

# Some words have spaces and - in the middle of the words. So we need to find out valid word
def get_valid_word(words):
    #randomly choice words from list
    word = random.choice(words)
    # the loop iterate until we get the word that does not have - or space on it.
    return word

def hungman():
    words = ["dog", "frog", "hog", "slob", "bacon", "avacado"]
    word = get_valid_word(words)
    #keep track what already been guessed in the word
    word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    #what the user had guessed
    used_letters = set()

    #getting user input
    while len(used_letters) < 8:
        #letters used
        print("You have used these letters: ")
        print(", ".join(used_letters))
        #what the current word is
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-'  for letter in word]
        print("Current word: ")
        print(", ".join(word_list))
        user_letter = str(input("Guess a letter : ")).lower()

        '''
        If this is the valid character in the alphabet that user has not use yet
        then user going to add this to his or her used letter list
        '''
        if user_letter in word_letters:
            used_letters.add(user_letter)

        if len(used_letters) == len(word_letters):
            print("you win")
    


hungman()
```

The number of things that were off in the code makes it hard to succinctly summarize what all was wrong.  However, if you work through what you had and compare it to what's here in a diff tool you'll find several things that kept the code from working correctly.

Also, you may find this of interest: https://github.com/dgwaldo/pytxtgames/blob/main/hangman.py

It's a Python Hangman game that I wrote as an example app for some students as fun. You may find some more ideas there...

Comment: The line [if used_letters.len() = word_letters.len():] throwing error. I corrected it as [if used_letters.len() == word_letters.len():] After that it throws error like ** `set' object has no attribute 'len' **

Comment: @Encipher, yes adjusted the code to fix that part.  There is still work to do here, but this should get you to the point you can finish it...